# Caching Data ( Redundant API Calls )

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter, and I've stumbled upon a problem I need advice in how to approach it. I'm building an app which uses navigator and [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). Now when I navigate to a certain route I have the bloc state pull some data from an API and show it. What I want to achieve is not call the API every time when I navigate to that route unless the app has been closed previously or a "pull to refresh" action has been made. How do I got about storing the data after the initial API call. I've tried with the [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc) but either I don't understand the point of the [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc) well or it's intention is not to do that. Thank you for the advice in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class AppState {
  static final AppState _instance = AppState._internal();
  factory AppState() => _instance;

  ApiResponseCustomClass apiResponse;

  AppState._internal() {
    // init things here if needed
  }
}
```

A simple way is to just make a state class where you will keep the result in, and then access it via `AppState().apiResponse` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [local_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage) to maintain your data locally. So every time you need to fetch data from API again and again. and you can clear data before closing the app.